# Custom form to send on outlook email through spring using freemarker (ftl template)

Tags: java, spring-boot, outlook, html-email, freemarker

I want to send email with form elements to end users. So, End users can fill up the form details within email and submit it.

I have created a ftl template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    This e-mail is for project approval :<br/>
                    <a href="">${projectName}</a><br/>
                    <br/>
                    <form action="" method="post" id="projectApprovalFrm">
                     Status Reason:<br>
                     <textarea name="statusReason"></textarea><br><br>
                    </form>
                    <input type="button" value="Reject" id="reject" />
                    <input type="button" value="Approve" id="approve" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
        <script>
        $( "#approve" ).click(function() {
          $("#projectApproveFrm").action( "http://localhost:8080/projectApproval" );
          $("#projectApproveFrm").submit();
        });
         $( "#reject" ).click(function() {
          $("#projectApproveFrm").action( "http://localhost:8080/projectReject" );
          $("#projectApproveFrm").submit();
        });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Spring code to sent email:

```
Mail mail = new Mail(); // Created POJO class to hold email properties
mail.setFrom("mail@outlook.id"); //Outlook mail id from mail sent   
mail.setTo("user@domain.com");  //receiver mail id
mail.setSubject("Test Email");      
                
MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();   
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,   
           MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());   
                
Template t = freemarkerConfig.getTemplate("email-project-approval-template.ftl");   
String html = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(t, mail.getModel());    
helper.setTo(mail.getTo()); 
helper.setText(html, true);
helper.setSubject(mail.getSubject());   
helper.setFrom(mail.getFrom()); 

javaMailSender.send(message);
```

Mails are been sent to end user. However, Form elements are visible in outlook

[image]

I also verified by webmail on browser where elements are visible but form is not getting submitted.

What should be done to overcome this issue? Is there any Java code needs to update or any changes needs to in ftl file. Does anyone have any ideas?

Or Is there any other way to send HTML form in email using JAVA?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably nothing to do with Java, but everything to do with the fact that forms work on only certain email environments - and Outlook is not one of them. See https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-interactive-forms-in-email/ for 2020 tests.

You can still send forms through email - but will need a fallback for Outlook (i.e. a link to a webpage with the form).

You can do that with Outlook-specific code like so (courtesy of Litmus):

CSS

```
.interactive-form {
    display: block !important;
    max-height: inherit !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.fallback-form {
    display: none;
}
 
body[data-outlook-cycle] .outlookshow{ display:block !important; width: auto !important; overflow: visible !important; float: none !important; max-height:inherit !important; max-width:inherit !important; line-height: auto !important; margin-top:0px !important; visibility:inherit !important;}
body[data-outlook-cycle] .outlookhide{ display:none !important; display:none; overflow:hidden; float:left; width:0px; max-height:0px; max-width:0px; line-height:0px; visibility:hidden; }
 
[class~="x_outlookshow"] { display:block !important; width: auto !important; overflow: visible !important; float: none !important; max-height:inherit !important; max-width:inherit !important; line-height: auto !important; margin-top:0px !important; visibility:inherit !important;}
[class~="x_outlookhide"] { display:none !important; display:none; overflow:hidden; float:left; width:0px; max-height:0px; max-width:0px; line-height:0px; visibility:hidden; }
 
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .fallback-form {
    display:block !important;
    width: auto !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    float: none !important;
    max-height:inherit !important;
    max-width:inherit !important;
    line-height: auto !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    visibility:inherit !important;
  }
  .interactive-form, 
  .interactive-form p, 
  .interactive-form label, 
  .interactive-form input  {
    display:none !important;
    display:none !important;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    max-height: 0px !important;
    max-width: 0px !important;
    line-height: 0px !important;
    visibility:hidden !important;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<!--[if mso | ie]>
<style>
.fallback-form {
  display: block !important;
  max-height: inherit !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
 
 
<!-- start FORM_INTERACTIVE -->
<!--[if (!mso)&amp;(gte IE 10)]> <! -- -->
<div class="interactive-form outlookhide" style="display:none; max-height:0; line-height:0; font-size:0; mso-hide:all;">
    [Insert Interactive Form code here]
</div>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!-- end FORM_INTERACTIVE -->
 
<!-- start FORM_FALLBACK -->
<div class="fallback-form outlookshow">
    [Insert fallback for form section here]
</div>
<!-- end FORM_FALLBACK -->
```

Comment: It is bottleneck situation, But thank you for the answer.